# How to retrieve Azure AD users with an alternate email address?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

How do I retrieve Azure AD users with an alternate email address tin a CSV file?

I tried this but the CSV `AlternateEmailAddresses` column is empty.

```
Get-AzADUser | select AlternateEmailAddresses | export-csv azureadusers.csv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested in my environment.

Please use Get-AzureADUser instead of Get-AzADUser as there continues to be a lack of properties returned when comparing "Get-AzureADUser" vs. "Get-AzADUser"

Please use the below command to export Azure AD users with alternate email address to csv file.

```
Get-AzureADUser |select UserPrincipalName , @{n='OtherMails'; e={$_.OtherMails -join ' '}} | export-csv azureadusers.csv
```

[image]

Reference : https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/10497

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it. I ended up figuring it out.

Comment: Glad to know that your issue has resolved. You can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

AzureAD is deprecated and the command "Get-AzureADUser" should not be used when not required. It also use Azure Active Directory Scope and is also deprecated and every scopes should use  Graph API.

The way you need to do your query with Az Powershell is like this :

> #**Get users with alternate emails:**
> *$users = Get-AzADUser -Select "otherMails", "Mail","Id","DisplayName", "UserPrincipalName"*
> #**Selecting users other mails:**
> *$users | Select OtherMail*

As you can see, there is alot here not making sense. Why Fetching "otherMails" when it is mapped to "OtherMail" property? MS is not even respecting his own standard...